# Pull Dataframes out of Nested Dictionary based on condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dictionary of dataframes called df_dict.

```
df_dict.keys()
dict_keys(['df1.test', 'df2.test', 'df3.test','df1_test','df2_test','df3_test'])
```

Each key is a separate dataframe that has its own columns and data associated with it.  How do I lift those  dataframes that DO NOT have (".") in their title out of the dictionary so they are dataframes in their own right, not part of the dictionary?

I know I can do the following, but it's cumbersome and I may be adding to this list in the future.

```
df1_test= pd.DataFrame(df_dict['df1_test'])
df2_test= pd.DataFrame(df_dict['df2_test'])
df3_test= pd.DataFrame(df_dict['df3_test'])
```

I'd like something that loops through the dictionary and creates a new dataframe each time.

```
for key in df_dict.keys():
  if !key.str.contains(pat = '.'): # how to negate? if key name does not contain a period
     key = pd.DataFrame(df_dict[key]) #i want the dataframes to be the key names
```

End goal is to have 3 dataframes outputed - df1_test, df2_test, df3_test

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your requirement you want to create DF names from the Dictionary. It is possible to create global names from strings and assign these to objects:

```
for key,df in df_dict.items():
    if '.' not in key:
        globals()[(key)] = df
```

The 3 selected DFs will then have the required names assigned df1_test, df2_test, df3_test and these can be used as required.